# Passing a multidimensional array through hidden input via POST

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

So I researched online to see how I can pass an array which I POST through form.

Here's what I did.

```
    $itemsArr = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totalPrice += $row['item_price'];
    $totalItemsOnCart += $row['quantity'];
    $itemId = $row['item_idPK'];
    $itemName = $row['item_name'];
    $itemPrice = $row['item_price'];
    $itemQty = $row['quantity'];
    $itemsArr[] = array($userId, $itemId, $itemQty);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$itemId."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$itemName."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$itemPrice."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$itemQty."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    }
```

Then, I used the foreach loop to iterate through the multidimensional array.

```
echo "<form class = 'BreadCode' action='Function_Cart.php' method='POST'>";
foreach($itemsArr as $value){
    print_r($value);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemsArr[]" value="'. $value. '">';
}
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='userId' value='$userId'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemId' value='$itemId'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='$itemQty'>";
    echo "<input class='PayButton' type='submit' name='Btn-pay' value='Pay'>";
    echo "</form>";
```

I keep getting an  "`Array to string conversion`" error with or without the `echo` for the hidden input within the `foreach()` loop

I haven't really tried sending an `array` via form through `POST` method in the past. I just don't know how to go about this.

Below is the result of `print_r()`

```
Array ( [0] => 5112 [1] => 105 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5112 [1] => 104 [2] => 1 )
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: you can pass it as`json`. before `foreach` `<input type="hidden" name="itemsArr" value="'<?php echo json_encode($itemsArr ); ?>. '">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to encode array to json and decode it on action page

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemsArr" value="'.json_encode($itemsArr). '">';
```

And at your action Page just decode it

```
$itemsArr = json_decode($_POST['itemsArr'],true)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have one problem when I decode it. It returns nothing when I try to echo var_dump($itemsArr) or print_r($itemsArr);

Comment: inspect element and check the input tag contain proper json data or not try to just print $_POST['itemsArr'] should it print something or note?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for place `foreach` and increase execution time. You can simply do that by using `json_encode`.

```
echo "<form class = 'BreadCode' action='Function_Cart.php' method='POST'>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemsArr" value="' . json_encode($itemsArr) . '">';

echo "<input type='hidden' name='userId' value='$userId'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemId' value='$itemId'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='$itemQty'>";
echo "<input class='PayButton' type='submit' name='Btn-pay' value='Pay'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Thanks. There's just one problem. I can't seem to get the value when I try json_decode($_POST['itemsArr'],true); It returns nothing or null.